# Kac Peterson paper on infinite wedge representation and MKP hierarchy

Tags: reference-request

I need a paper:

V. Kac, D. Peterson, Lectures on the infinite wedge representation and the MKP hierarchy, Seminaire de Math. Superieures, Les Presses de L'Universite de Montreal 102 (1986), 141-186.

Does anyone know how I could find a copy of it?

Comment: Me too, please!

Comment: 
Do you have tried to contact Prof. Victor Kac? Prof. Victor email: kac@math.mit.edu